# Need to ask something about Sony PCM-50

Tags: sony, sony-pcm-d50, field-recording, sound-design

I am thinking of buying one Sony PCM-50 for capturing sounds i am going to use in a video game. And cause i am tight on budget i d like to ask if i can connect external directional mics on this portable recorder (without the XLR-1 adapter witch is going to cost me another 500 euros or so!)

if i use it with a shotgun mic that takes batteries am i going to need something else except an xlr to mini jack adapter to be able to write on pcm50?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PCM D50 does not provide phantom power, so you'll have to use a powered mic and an xlr to minijack adapter.

I use the Rode NTG-2 with it here and there and it works fine.

I found out that it was far easier to hang the recorder from my neck than to use a bag though.  that preamp or connector even get breathed on and your recording is broken.

Answer (score 2):

i think this was answered somewhere else on this site already. you can use the d50/m10 with ntg-2 and similar mics by just using a xlr to minijack cable. these are commonly used by filmmakers too and you can find them in stores that sell audio/eng cables. in Germany, Thomann sell a "pro snake kamerakabel" female xlr to "dual mono" minijack. the minijack connector fits the m10 (and i guess d50) fine, but be wary of the xlr one in windy conditions (e.g. when using a softie).

Answer (score 2):

You could use any other portable phantom power source besides XLR-1. AKG B18 is one choice. A Sound Devices MP-1 also costs less than XLR-1 and contains a superb preamp, so you could hook it to PCM-D50 using line level.

Answer (score 0):

After all the research i done (mostly in here) i end up in purchasing one Sony PCM-D50 portable recorder.

The verdict? Awesome! I would like to say a big thanks to all of you with your comments and point of views for helping me.

I already tested the pcm-d50 with onboard mics, a shure sm57 and a cheap shotgun mic. They all sound fantastic. The onboard mics are crisp and clear and the preamps that drive the external mics are very very good as well!

Answer (score 0):

**I recently purchased a Sony PCM-M10 and was wondering the same thing..
I guess a Rode NTG-2 is next on the list, unless anybody else has any suggestions for close sfx/impact recording..?**

Comment: i purchased a very cheap Thomann EM9600 for like 50 euros and i can work very good till i get a better one! 